# setting proxy in facebook graph api in python

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

How can I set the proxy in this facebook graph api?

I already have been watching [this article](http://facebook-sdk.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html).
But how can I use this?

This is my code

```
import facebook
import json

def pp(o):
    print json.dumps(o, indent=1)


v_proxies = {
  "http" : "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080",
  "https": "https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080",
}

ACCESS_TOKEN ='xxx'
g = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN, proxies = v_proxies)

pp(g.get_object('me'))
pp(g.get_connections('me', 'friends'))
```